# How to create and populate new column in 2nd Pandas dataframe based on condition in 1st df?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like the following.

```
df1 = {'City' :['London', 'Basel', 'Kairo'], 'Country': ['UK','Switzerland','Egypt']}

    City    Country
0   London  UK
1   Basel   Switzerland
2   Kairo   Egypt
```

Now I want to assign a new column called 'Continent' that should be filled based on the values.

So df2 should look like:

```
    City    Country      Continent
0   London  UK           Europe
1   Basel   Switzerland  Europe
2   Kairo   Egypt        Africa
```

So df1 inidicates the values for the new column in df2. How do I do this in the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

With a dictionary of country->continent, you can pass it pd.DataFrame.replace() method, like this:

```
df['Continent'] = df['Country'].replace(country_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you!  If I have many values though, creating a dictionary is not so efficient, is it? How can I ensure that several values in column 1 create a new value in a new column 2, while the rest of the values in column 1 make up for another value in column 2? E.g. Values : a,b, and c in column 1 should cause "label" in column 2. The rest of the values in column 1 (d,e,f,......z)  should lead to "no label" in column 2. How do I do this?

Comment: It's true that replace may be somewhat slow, but you should test it anyway and see if this is the case. Regarding your problem, you can try map() instead, it seems to be faster, too. It accepts not only dicts, but functions, so you can give it something like
`df['Continent'] = df['Country'].map(lambda x: country_dict.get(x, 'default value'))`